# how can i use xibs and storyboards together?

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, xib

Is it possible to put some xib files into a storyboard project. If so can I make it so when someone pushes a button in the storyboard it goes to the xib files. For example i have a storyboard with some views and I'm trying to put a calendar in it but the calendar uses xibs so I want it when I press a button it will go to the xib.

Comment: Also i am pretty new to objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create XIB when you create connector.h and connector.m by selecting it subclass of UIViewController and click on the checkbox for: "With XIB for User Interface". If you have created already .m & .h files then you can just add a new GUI file by selecting View from the window & finally setting its Controller Custom class to connector You could have StoryBoard and XIB together in the same project.

For presenting the view Controller you could use the following code:

```
YourViewController *viewController=[[YourViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerName" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In case of NavigatinController:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can mix storyboards and xibs. If the user presses a button in a view that comes from a storyboard, you can use initWithNibName:bundle: to create an instance of a controller whose view is in a xib file, then present that, or push to it if you're using a navigation controller.